# Disabling gesture in react-navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm creating a project and Initially, it has two `stack` screens. `SettingScreen and ChangePasswordScreen` and the one `drawer`.

```
 export const SettingStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
 
    <SettingStack.Navigator>
        <SettingStack.Screen
            name="Settings"
            component={SettingScreen}
        />
        <SettingStack.Screen
            name="ChangePassword"
            component={ChangePasswordScreen}
        />
    </SettingStack.Navigator>
```

);

`app.js`

```
             <Drawer.Navigator
                        drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
                    >
                        
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingStackScreen} />
                    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

using this code `Drawer` is accessible on both screen but I want to access drawer only first `screen` of SettingStackScreen not on others screen.
I tried `gestureEnabled` but it disabling the `drawer` swipe gesture in the both screen.

Answer (score 0):

give this a go:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />
  edgeWidth={-1} // don't allow slide-to-open
>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingStackScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

[from the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#edgewidth):

> edgeWidth
>
> Allows for defining how far from the edge of the content view the
> swipe gesture should activate.
>
> This is not supported on Web.

If you go with this solution you're gonna need a burger menu or something that opens the drawer menu, something like:

```
<BurgerMenuButton onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
```